# How to clean dataset in order to fit to a curve?

Tags: outliers, nonlinear-regression, curve-fitting, data-preprocessing

I'm trying to fit a dataset to a curve for while, but I'm not managing.
The goal is to obtain a curve with equation that fits the data so I can get the parameter x to any value of y.
The blue dataset is the measurement of the soil parameter at the field, and the orange dataset is the measurement of the parameter at the lab.
[image]

I already have limited the min and max value for values that make sense in real life, and I have applied the outlier cleaner for the quartile of 0.25/0.75

```
def remove_outlier(df_in, col_name):
    q1 = df_in[col_name].quantile(0.25)
    q3 = df_in[col_name].quantile(0.75)
    iqr = q3-q1 #Interquartile range
    fence_low  = q1-1.5*iqr
    fence_high = q3+1.5*iqr
    df_out = df_in.loc[(df_in[col_name] > fence_low) & (df_in[col_name] < fence_high)]
    return df_out
```

and when I try to fit the data with scipy:

```
def fit_ocr(x,a,b):
    return a/x + b
param, param_cov = curve_fit(fit_ocr, x, y)
a = param[0]
b = param[1]
test_fit = fit_ocr(x,a,b)
```

That's what I get:

[image]

Comment: The usual least squares method for fitting a curve requires to define one variable as predictor and one as response. This does not work with the red "trendline", because whatever variable you choose as predictor, there is no unique response value for a given predictor. Are you instead looking for surface fitting, e.g. moving least squares?

Comment: Yes! probably this is what I need, could you give me some more information, please?

Comment: This is just a restatement of your original question.  Please clarify the original by editing it rather than reposting a new version of your question.

Comment: Jennifer wrote: "could you give me some more information". As the question is already closed, here some suggesions instead of a proper answer. Most work on surface reconstruction is for 3D data. For 2D data, there is an implementation in CGAL https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction/index.html#Chapter_Advancing_Front_Surface_Reconstruction. This will result in a polygon of the surface which you then can further process, e.g. by splie fitting or local orthogonal least squares through the points close to the surface.

Comment: @cdalitz thank you for the suggestion, I have done some research, and is not what I need, I have handled it manually. Thank you

Comment: How did you solve your problem? As the question is closed because it lacks a description of your problem, you might edit the question and describe the problem and the solution.

Comment: I used least squares as mentioned here https://jkp-ads.com/articles/leastsquares.asp